# Initializing an array type to an object javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase-realtime-database, angular8

I hava an interface called Products

```
 export interface Products{
    category: string;
    imageUrl: string;
    price: number;
    title: string;
 }
```

I have a variable in my component of type products array

```
products: Products[];
```

I am trying to map my response from my service to the products variable, but I get this error Type

```
'{}[]' is not assignable to type 'Products[]'
```

and I don't know what i'm doing wrong

```
this.subscription = this.productService
  .getAll()
  .subscribe(
    products =>
      (this.products = products.map(p => ({ ...(p.payload.val() as {}) }))),
  )
```

Comment: What does your method `p` does? (Within the map function)

Comment: sorry that's a mistake. should be p => ({...p.payload.val() as {}}

Comment: Does something called `payload` have a *method*?  Most payloads I've seen are plain data objects.

Comment: @gbubemismith does the `p` refer to products?

Comment: You're explicitly doing an `as {}` in there; do you mean to do `as Product` or leave off the `as` clause if it's type inferable? You're basically _telling_ the compiler to make an `{}[]`.

Comment: thanks resolved it with as Product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this assignment clause:

```
this.products = products.map(p => ({
  ...(p.payload.val() as {})
}))
```

...you're casting `p.payload.val()` as type `{}` and also spreading that into an empty object (to clone it?), which still keeps its type as `{}`. Therefore, `products.map(...)` has type of `{}[]`, a.k.a. `Array<{}>`. Since `this.products` is a `Product[]`, the type is incompatible.

If `p.payload.val()` is already of type `Product`, then there's no need to cast anything:

```
this.products = products.map(p => p.payload.val())

// or if you need that cloning stuff...

this.products = products.map(p => ({ ...p.payload.val() }))
```

If it's *not* of type `Product`, cast to `Product` instead of `{}`:

```
this.products = products.map(p => p.payload.val() as Product)

// or if cloning...

this.products = products.map(p => {
  return { ...p.payload.val() } as Product
});
```